# VIM changed behaviour on me - jump to line : is broken

Tags: vim

Smething *just* happened in the last 20 minutes or so to my vim.  I must have hit *something*, but I can't figure it out, and nothing will get it back to the 'real' behaviour.

I've always used : to jump to a line number.  Now, when I hit : then a number - (1-9), vim instead goes in to "insert" mode and inserts a letter.  (1=q, 2=r, 3=s, 4=t, 5=w, etc.)

Trying to search around for this is worse than looking for a needle in a haystack!

Any ideas as to what sort of secret "mode" I've enabled?  And better yet, how I might get back to normality?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you hit caps lock on accident?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you've done there but you can also jump to a specific line number by entering the line number and then hitting <kbd>G</kbd> (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>).

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> on its own will take you to the last line of the file.

Comment: Recommenting here: It's even more basic than what I'd described.  Hitting any number key will automatically enter insert mode.  It's nothing to do with the colon key.

So, I can't enter "125G" to jump to that line because the "1" auto-enters insert mode (and enters 'q').

Thanks for suggestion tho.

Answer (score 1):

It could be your shell and not VIM.  If restarting VIM doesn't fix your problem, try opening a new shell and using VIM there.  If nothing works, move your .vimrc file and any shell start ups out of the way (by renaming, not deleting, of course), open a new shell, and VIM.  If that doesn't work, try a new keyboard. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Closing and opening vim should reset whatever you funky mode you've discovered.  If not, you've got something profoundly weird going on -- vim doesn't store settings that are turned on while in the file.

BTW, you're totally ruining my "vim doesn't break" meme.

Comment: Sorry, but's it's 100% hosed up.  Closing vim did nada.  

VIM breaks, and when it does, you're profoundly hosed.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've no idea what it was, but rebooting the computer - Macbook running leopard - seemed to work.

I'd tried new shells to no effect.  I just didn't want to have to reboot.

See - macs have problems too!  :(

Thanks for all the quick responses from all y'all.  Hopefully I won't have to figure that one out again.